# Quick Exponent Clarification

Tags: notation, exponentiation, big-numbers

$N = 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5}}}}$

In the following equation is N equal to $5^{5^4}$ or $5^{(5^{(5^{(5^5)})})}$?

One of them is huge compared to the other, so knowing this would make a huge difference. Thanks.

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: $$N = 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5^{\displaystyle 5}}}}=$$
$$N = 5^{\displaystyle 3125^{\displaystyle 3125}}$$

Comment: @JanEerland exponentiation is not associative in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented, your number would normally be interpreted as

$$
5^{\displaystyle\left(5^{\left(5^{\left(5^{\left(5^{}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}
$$
or, in [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) notation, ${}^55$.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend that you're a computer trying to parse that expression. You see 5 raised to something, so you first need to parse and evaluate that something. But that something is 5 raised to something else, so you need to parse and evaluate that something else first. Keep going that way and you'll see that you need to parse and evaluate the top-most $5^5 = 3125$. Then you go back down one level, and so on. The result is huge!